# Django Email Already Exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-custom-user

So i have tried to create Custome Users for my project Provider and Seeker, also i have create a register view, however, whenever i want to add a user (provider) it tells me that the email already exists, despite there is no users in the database yet

1. I have tried to remove the UniqueValidator from the ProviderSerializer and implement the logic of finding duplicate emails in the view
2. I have tried to save the user to the database then check if there is a email duplicate

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAdminUser
from .models import Provider, Seeker
from .serializer import ProviderSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import serializers

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def Register(request):
    if request.data.get('work_email'):
        seri = ProviderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if seri.is_valid():
            try:
                user = seri.save()
                try:
                    group = Group.objects.get(name='Provider')
                    user.groups.add(group)
                except Group.DoesNotExist:
                    return Response({"Message": "Exception at group assigning"})
            except serializers.ValidationError as e:
                return Response(e.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return Response({"Message": "User created successfully"})
        else:
            return Response(seri.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response({"Message": "No Work_email"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.


class GenericUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,null = True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True,db_index=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS= []

class Provider(GenericUser):
    work_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False, null = True)


class Seeker(GenericUser):
    ed_level = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Comment: So exactly *what* do you want to register, do you want to *create* a new `Provider`/`Seeker`, or *link* to an existing one?